# In De Broglie's Explanation for Bohr's Quantization Condition, why do we not use 2πr = n λ/2, why do we use 2πr = n λ?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, wavelength, orbitals

> [image: **De Broglie's explanation for Bohr's Quantization Condition**]

In de Broglie's explanation for Bohr's quantization condition, why do we not use $2\pi r = n\lambda/2$, why do we use $2\pi r = n\lambda$?

We know that in waves on strings, for standing waves creation in a string between two rigid supports, we use "Length of String" $ = n \lambda/2$. Why do we not use a similar concept here?

Comment: Draw a picture with, say, three-and-one-half wavelengths going around a circle. Do you see a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the perimeter is not a whole number multiple of ${\lambda}$, the next time the wave completes a revolution it will not coincide with the previous wave. The waves will superimpose and over a period of time eventually cancel itself. The waves must perfectly coincide to exist. Hence the allowed orbits have a radius which satisfies $2{\pi}r = n{\lambda}$