# Why does $n \lambda = 2 \pi r$ cause a standing wave in a circle?

Tags: waves, atomic-physics

Repeat of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/504908/in-de-broglies-explanation-for-bohrs-quantization-condition-why-do-we-not-use) since I did not find the answer satisfying as I do not see how the wave would destructively interfere with itself if the circumference is not an integer multiple of the wavelength and the previous answer lacks a visual representation. I know the Bohr model is outdated and is an incorrect interpretation, but I just want to understand why we don't use $\frac{n}{2} \lambda = 2 \pi r$ to express a standing wave just like we did on a string. An animation or a set of images would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, I have it linked so that no one would reference it as I did not find the answer satisfying.

Comment: To reopen this question, please clarify *why* the accepted answer at the duplicate question is inadequate.

Comment: I have deleted my previous comment as I had misunderstood the linked question to be by the OP. Rob's comment sums up my revised view. **Edit:** Regardless of clarifying as to why the accepted answer to the duplicate question is inadequate, the OP should explain how their question is different from the linked question. A lack of an adequate answer to the original question should not be sufficient for posting a duplicate.

Comment: I just want to understand why and I cannot find a good answer online so I came here, I do not understand why you are so bothered by my post. I have clarified why I found the other answer not satisfying. Please if you do not know how to answer my question just leave it be, hopefully someone can help me. I wish this community was more welcoming to new comers .

Comment: @realanswers The reason for the policy of not allowing duplicating posts is precisely to ensure that one can actually find an answer to a given question. If PSE were to let duplicate questions remain open, the answers to the same question would be distributed across various posts that someone like yourself would have to scour through to find the answer that they find most satisfying. Under the current policy, to the extent that it is implemented, this would not happen -- one would find all the answers to a given question in one place. Hope it makes sense :-)

Comment: You can read up more on the policy [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates). In general, if you are unsatisfied with any policy, you can always raise a question either on the [Physics Meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/) or on the network-wide [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).